# Ending song episode 13 Moretsu Pirates (sub)

Tags: music, bodacious-space-pirates

I am unable to verify if official legal streaming services have the same ending theme as illegal ones since this show is unavailable in my country through legal services, if someone could verify this for me I would appreciate it.

So as for non legal one I used gogo. I won't put any links or such in here as I encourage everyone to support the studios as much as they can.

At the ending of episode 13 there is a different song being played as outro as opposed to all previous and future episodes. This is simply the odd one out. This song is extremely relaxing and has a lovely overal soundtrack. However I am simply unable to identify this piece.

It starts at episode 13 (22:07 if you use most of the streaming services) right where it shows the episode number (see screenshot). This lasts for almost 2 minutes with plenty of vocals. I don't understand japanese so writing down the lyrics is a no go for me. It might even be written in the credits shown during the song.
[image: Screenshot of where the song starts]

The name of the soundtrack would be the most ideal outcome. However after extensive research I wasn't able to find the slightest hint about it. I might have looked at the wrong places, but simply stating the vocalist and maybe even group/band would be accepted as well if after a couple of weeks no results are found.

Comment: i know there's 2 ED for the series, one is *LOST CHILD* and i have a second ED Soundtrack on my iPod with 2 songs, *Black Holy* and other one which is all gibberish (probably in Japanese which the characters weren't converted well) but also there is a *Black Holy Inst* which could be Insert? unforutnally i can't give an artist name as that got garbled to so i might need to check if my rip's original data didn't get garbled to give proper names for 2 possibilities

Comment: [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=11399) however lists the Ending Theme for Episode 13 as *""Toumei na Yozora ~Shibataku Hoshi ni Tsutsumarete~" (透明な夜空 ~瞬く星に包まれて~; "Clear Sky ~wrapped by a twinking star~") by Mikako Komatsu"* and Mikako Komatsu is listed as the artist for *Black Holy* which is listed as an Insert Song, could be the garbled names i have

Comment: @Memor-X it definitely isn't Lost Child, that one is the main ending track. I am unable to find Black Holy easily, so I will dig around tomorrow (it is 1am already here), but the name you provided from ANN might just be the answer. Her voice sounds at the very least similar. Thanks for the info, I truelly appreciate it!

Comment: @Memor-X Toumei na Yozora was indeed the song used which was covered by Mikako Komatsu, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to Memor-X I was pointed to the right direction in order to pinpoint the soundtrack used. Due to it being unavailable in my country I can't get my hands on the original album. I was able to verify this with the instrumental version, preview samples and a non legal version.

The name of the soundtrack is **Toumei na Yozora** *~Mabataku Hoshi ni Tsutsumarete~* covered by **Komatsu Mikako** which had the street release date of April 25th 2012.